# Umbraco 6 - Published page throws 404 in specific scenarios

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I am running an instance of Umbraco 6.1.x and it has started throwing 404 on published pages.

My page structure is as follows,

Content
 Home
   About
   Course
   ...
 Component
   Home
   About
   Course
Where component holds all resources and modules (HTML sections and stuff) for a page and using a partial view macro I dynamically load all components at runtime for a specific page.

We are facing an issue where we get 404 on every page after a full republish once we hit the HomePage. Before hitting home page they are all fine, but the moment we hit the homepage they are all throwing 404. By overriding the handlers I found out that they are hitting ~/umbraco/RenderMvc!

Any idea what can cause this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

It is actually throwing:

No template exists to render the document at url '/'

considering the aforementioned scenario.

I have proper allowed template setup and property on nodes are showing the correct template associated with the respective items. Not sure why it's losing template info. I can force it to load under correct template using ?altTemplate=templateName.

Some pointers, we have a view in Views/Shared folder (apart from macro partials) tied to a surface controller.

One thing I would like to say is, we are using nested (library.RenderMacroContent with Umbraco markup) in our partial views and I have realized that the whole page throws 404 if there's a page with a link to the broken page which is broken (i.e. page got re-created and on t==e of the components is holding a link to the page with previous id). Suggestions?

Comment: Any idea anyone? Still don't have much of a lead on my side. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

did you get to the bottom of this? We're having exactly the same problem at the moment, on the same version of Umbraco.

I've noticed that when it happens, the umbraco.config becomes either corrupt or rolls back to a much, much earlier version, with all sorts of attributes missing. This lead us to believe it was a sync issue between the DB and umbraco.config.

We initially thought we had solved it by deleting App_Data > TEMP > ExamineIndex and recycling the app pool etc. Maybe give this ago, as it fixed it for a while for us, but alas, the demon has reared its ugly head once more. We are still in a full on dev stage though, so the constant changing may be complicating it further for us - perhaps it will be a fix for you.

If you have any more info, or even a fix, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, I *think* I've solved this now, but only time will tell. Try emptying your recycle bin & then republish entire site.

I managed to consistently recreate the bug using IIS SEO site analysis. Each time I did this, the log threw up an error 'cannot find node id xyz', turns out that (and other) nodes were in the recycle bin. Upon emptying it the errors stopped. Good luck!